# What is the copy function in web console in Firefox 60.5.1?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Seem the copy function in global scope but it is not in the window scope.
I run on Firefox 60.5.1 Debian Stretch.
Is any documentation for the global copy function?

```
>> copy
function ()
>> window.copy
undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the [console utilities API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities)* and can only be called from the console, therefore it is not part of the `window` scope, `copy` is defined as:

> `copy(object)` copies a string representation of the specified object to the clipboard.

---

*Yes, that is from the Chrome docs, I could not find docs for Firefox, however they usually behave the same.